# Orthogonal Matrix relation

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I am having trouble with this expression:- $ \sum_i a_{ij} a_{ik} = \delta_{jk} $ What does it mean?

I kind of understood from the section that the coordinate matrix is made up of direction cosines, so $a_{ij}$ is the cosine of the angle between $\hat{x}'_i$ and $\hat{x}_j$ ... so if orthogonal it's cos90 = 0, when j = k then cos 0 = 1.

The jth row of A $\equiv$ kth col of $A^T$makes sense, but when I try and calculate an example, lets say for i=1, I get mixed up. does j iterate with k?

Comment: It's probably supposed to be a sum over $i$. It tells you the entries of what you get when you multiply a matrix $A$ by its transpose, and the $\delta_{jk}$ is indicating that $AA^T = I$

Comment: It is $\sum_{\color{red}i}a_{ij}a_{ik}=\delta_{jk}$, i.e. $j$-th row of the *transpose* matrix × $k$-th column of the matrix.